# Why can't programs compiled using GCC be run using DOSbox while those compiled using Borland(Turbo C) can?

Tags: c, gcc, turbo-c, dosbox

Years ago,I had created a program using TurboC IDE and This program can also be run using [DOSbox](http://www.dosbox.com/). Now,when I tried to run any program which was compiled using GCC in DOSbox,this message came:

> This program cannot be run in DOS mode

So my question is,Why isn't it possible to run programs compiled using GCC in DOSbox,while those compiled from TurboC are?

PS:The reason that I want to run them in DOSbox is that I want to run those programs in my phone(which has DOSbox installed).

Comment: They are probably by default compiled with a Windows console or 32/64-bit executable stub. Check the compile targets for `gcc`. (But I seriously doubt "MS DOS" is still available.)

Comment: You want a DOS cross compiler. You cannot compile your program on the host system and expect it to run on another completely unrelated system. Alternatively, compile the program in DOSBox itself, although that sounds like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @remyabel, shouldn't you be able to expect it if you wrote your code according to the standard avoiding any extensions?

Comment: @Chief That guarantees (or rather enforces) portability across **compilers**, not across **systems**. Binary compatibility is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because MS DOS is 16-bit operating system and has no support for the 32-bit programs. Also modern operating systems has much stricter view on the direct hardware access, so modern programs must work through some hardware abstraction layers, which are also missing in the MS DOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GCC distribution called "DJGPP" which enables programs to be compiled using GCC, and uses DPMI to achieve this. Dos Protected Mode Interface, you have to run the program in protected mode, basically. There are other C environments such as Watcom that did the same thing, but I don't think Borland ever did anything with it.